# How to process SAML Response in Nodejs to validate SAML response

Tags: node.js, saml, saml-2.0

I am new to SAML and have recently tried the SAML POC using Azure AD as Identity provider(Idp) and Dropbox as Service provider(SP) and was able to successfully authenticate and login to Dropbox.

I want to programmatically process(validate) the SAML response token that was returned by Identity provider so that I can login to service provider.

I am looking for guidance/pointers/reference around processing and validating SAML Token in Nodejs, so that I can authenticate user against Service Provider.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code snippets of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following library to perform SAML response validation:
https://github.com/node-saml/node-saml

It has straightforward instructions as to how SAML is to be parsed.

For diving deeper into SAML flow, check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-6QSEqDJPo

To get started, simply install library using:

```
npm i node-saml
```

Then, use the library as follows:

```
const { SAML } = require("node-saml");

const options = {};
const saml = new SAML(options);
```

For passing the right Options, you can refer here: https://github.com/node-saml/node-saml

Another alternative is to use passport-saml, linked here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-saml